# How to set the DefaultSize of a Custom Control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

*The answer is simple, just override the DefaultSize property*.
This doesn't work in this case.

```
Public Class DRbox
    Inherits ListBox
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultSize As Size
        Get
            Return New Size(200, 26)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
    End Sub
End Class
```

After dragging this Control to a Form, the size is a square as the default of the ListBox.
Removing the `MyBase.New()` doesn't change the result.
What do I miss?

Comment: Just set `Me.Size = New Size(200, 26)` in the Constructor. Calling `MyBase.New()` is useless: it has nothing to do with this and it's called anyway, no matter if you do it explicitly or not. -- Note that this Size is set as the default only when Users drop the Control on a Form, not if they *design it* on the Form while dragging it from the ToolBox.

Answer (score 0):

The property you have used doesn't work on ListBox.
If you need to set something as default value regard visual properties (Width, Height etc..) you have to do that in a point that your ListBox is placed/painted on her Parent.
The code below gives an idea:

```
Public Class DRbox
    Inherits ListBox

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
        AddHandler Me.Layout, Sub() Me.Size = New Size(400, 100)
        'Me.Size = New Size(400, 100) Or directly this to allow resizing 
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Are you sure about what you're doing here? This doesn't set a *default Size*, this prevents the control from being resized. BTW, since you have a Custom control here, you don't subscribe to its events, you override the methods; meaning, you should override `OnLayout` (in case you actually want to do something when the Control changes its layout).

Comment: Based on “what I understood” seems OP wants that, even I know what you want to say. So, yes override OnLayout it’s more well-defined (although exits other ways more efficient, in my opinion) but as I wrote before in my answer the code “ shows a way ” near/similar possible to OP code posted.

Comment: As mentioned, this **prevents** the Control from being resized. -- What *other more efficient ways* than overriding `OnLayout()` or any other method that raises the event? There are no other ways. What would *more efficient* mean?

Comment: @Jimi I repeat: 1-I know that. 2- Based on “what I understood” seems OP wants that  3- the better way is to set directly the desired size on “InitilazeComponent” in order to have an initial Size.

Comment: Or directly `Me.Size = New Size(400, 100)` without  `AddHandler Me.Layout, Sub()` on the `New` constructor

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The question is not how to set the initial size of the control, that is simple, but why it's not set by the default size as it should be.

Comment: @user2645606 It's not true the default size doesn't work.. The default size works well. My answer was based only on ListBox which is a kind of Control that ignore this property. Your code in other Controls/ Containers works perfectly. But not in ListBox, Label etc..